# Convolve two 2-dimensional arrays with mask in python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, mask, convolution

I have image with mask (and some kernel). 
I would like to do 2d convolution on image but only on pixels that in the mask, let's say it only 5% of the image. Can I somehow use scipy.signal.convolve2d or other function or I should implement it by myself with nested loop? To run convolve2d on entire image and paste only mask's pixels is a option but I prefer something faster

Comment: Any explain why the downvote?

Comment: Some people think that a question without code is a bad question. I don't agree with that.

Comment: How large is the kernel? For a sufficiently large kernel it might be worth while writing your own loop (rather than pasting in the pixels under the mask from a full-image convolution).

Comment: 3x3, 5x5 or maybe 7x7

Comment: Then it's fairly trivial to compute the full-image convolution.